# Upgrade laravel 5.5 to 7

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Hi team I need help to upgrade my existing project which is on **laravel 5.5** but i need to upgrade it on **7**. So what i have to change so that my project run and may not affect by update version.

My `composer.json` file :

```
"require": {
   "php": ">=7.0.0",
   "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
   "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
   "intervention/image": "^2.4",
   "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
   "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
   "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
   "mews/captcha": "^2.1"
}
```

Comment: Laravel has an [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) for each version, you could try to follow those

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can check some of the requirements at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade, or may be you want to recreate a new project, you can check it out at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation.